# couldn't initiate a new react-native app because iOS environment is not properly set

Tags: react-native

first time Mac user trying to start a new react-native application. After doing this:

```
npx react-native init project_adji --template react-native-template-typescript
```

it fails with the following message:

```
✔ Downloading template
✔ Copying template
✔ Processing template
✔ Installing Bundler
✖ Installing CocoaPods dependencies (this may take a few minutes)
error warn Multiple Podfiles were found: ios/Podfile,vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods-core/Podfile. Choosing ios/Podfile automatically. If you would like to select a different one, you can configure it via "project.ios.sourceDir". You can learn more about it here: https://github.com/react-native-community/cli/blob/master/docs/configuration.md

✖ Installing CocoaPods dependencies (this may take a few minutes)
error Error: Looks like your iOS environment is not properly set. Please go to https://reactnative.dev/docs/next/environment-setup and follow the React Native CLI QuickStart guide for macOS and iOS.
```

I updated the ruby via rbenv to the required version to reach this point (ruby 2.7.5). I couldn't find the exact issue with my setup.

Any tips?

Answer (score 2):

I had exact the same issue here. After some research, I solved by following these steps:

```
gem uninstall cocoapods

sudo xcodebuild -license accept
```

Then created a test project to see where if everything works fine by following:

```
npx react-native init tempProject --skip-install

cd tempProject

yarn install

cd ios

bundle install

bundle exec pod install
```